# Show only tagged commits in git log

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to show a git log, ordered by commits, showing their dates, and also, showing only commits which have tags.

Our webhost has an automated deploy system, and when a particular commit is pushed to production, it gets a certain tag on it. I am troubleshooting an issue, and I want to look at only those commits that have been on production.

I was able to make a git alias, which I call `nanolog`, like this:

```
nanolog = log --date-order --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --format='%C(yellow)%cd%Creset  %h  \"%s\"  %Cred%cn %Cgreen(%cr)'
```

which gives me a log looking like this:

```
2019-06-17 23:39:43  13f7e5f89  "Merge branch 'live-config' into int"  Webhost (3 weeks ago)
2019-06-17 23:24:20  32b6141dc  "Merge branch 'live-config' into int"  User Name (3 weeks ago)
```

I've looked at [the documentation for `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), and in the section about `--format`, which is what I used to specify which information is displayed in my `nanolog` alias, I did not find any way to display tags. I looked at the [pretty formats documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats), and likewise did not find a way to specify tag information.

In the stock `git log`, you see tags next to the commit hash:

```
commit d1d59f2fe151d1eb240b453e6efe76e4dfe13a93 (tag: webhost_test_198, tag: webhost_live_114, origin/06-24, 06-24)
Merge: 13f7e5f89 143b58189
Author: Webhost <webhost@webhost.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 21 20:25:24 2019 +0000

    Merged int into master
```

It's fairly laborious and somewhat error-prone to scroll through the stock `git log`, which does include tags information, along with all the other untagged commits. How can I get a brief log that shows only commits with tags?

Ideally I would like something like this:

```
2019-06-17 23:39:43  13f7e5f89 (tag: webhost_test_198, tag: webhost_live_114, origin/06-24, 06-24) "Merge branch 'live-config' into int"  Webhost (3 weeks ago)
2019-06-03 23:24:20  32b6141dc (tag: webhost_test_197, tag: webhost_live_113,)  "Merge branch 'live-config' into int"  User Name (5 weeks ago)
```

Comment: You're looking for `--simplify-by-decoration` and the `%d` formatter.

Comment: @jthill Would you care to add that as an answer?

Comment: @jthill ...but decorations (either through `--simplify-by-decoration` flag or using `%d` placeholder in a format pattern) consist not only of tags but also branches. @user151841 If branch information is not too much noise for the output you wanted, and also IF jthill doesn't answer himself, I'll eventually go for a quick explanation of his suggestion.

Comment: @RomainValeri I can filter what I don't want using `| grep tag`, it's a good enough answer for my problem at hand. However, if you'd like to post another answer, please feel free : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from a simple `--oneline` output on a mock repo and only last three commits

```
git log --oneline -3

4c37e97 fixed a bug in sub-feature F1
d9c4599 added sub-feature F1
06014cb changed part XYZ
```

Now if we add *decorations* (references pointing to commits, namely tags and branches) with the `--decorate` flag :

```
git log --oneline --decorate -3

4c37e97 (HEAD -> feature/abc) fixed a bug in sub-feature F1
d9c4599 added sub-feature F1
06014cb (tag: release/1.22) changed part XYZ
```

And at this point you can also add the `--simplify-by-decoration` flag to filter out commits not referenced by any tag/branch

```
git log --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration -3

4c37e97 (HEAD -> feature/abc) fixed a bug in sub-feature F1
06014cb (tag: release/1.22) changed part XYZ
eec8aad (master) some older change
```

But in your case with a specific format, you have the `%d` to this effect.

If we modify your `nanolog`, which in my example outputs the following :

```
git nanolog -3

2019-07-08 19:19:46  4c37e97  "fixed a bug in sub-feature F1"  Romain (69 seconds ago)
2019-07-08 19:19:11  d9c4599  "added sub-feature F1"  Romain (2 minutes ago)
2019-07-08 19:18:26  06014cb  "changed part XYZ"  Romain (2 minutes ago)
```

into this one

```
    nanolog2 = log --date-order --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --format='%C(yellow)%cd%Creset  %h  \"%d %s\"  %Cred%cn %Cgreen(%cr)'
```

...we'll obtain

```
git nanolog2 -3

2019-07-08 19:19:46  4c37e97  " (HEAD -> feature/abc) fixed a bug in sub-feature F1"  Romain (12 minutes ago)
2019-07-08 19:19:11  d9c4599  " added sub-feature F1"  Romain (13 minutes ago)
2019-07-08 19:18:26  06014cb  " (tag: release/1.22) changed part XYZ"  Romain (14 minutes ago)
```

Finally, yes, you can pipe this to a `grep "(tag:"` or maybe just `grep tag` to filter out commits with only branches but no tags.

Comment: Nice work! : ) In your last comment, don't you mean `grep tag` to filter out commits that have no tag(s)?

Comment: @user151841 At first I reread my sentence and thought I had mistyped it, but although the formulation might be somewhat confusing, I wrote "*to filter **out*** commits with only branches", meaning that we keep only commits with tags. I fully admit the double negation was probably making it unclear. Thanks anyway for your vigilant eye and word of encouragement.